# Start the selenium server when Linux boots

Tags: linux, selenium-webdriver

I am having a linux machine dedicated to run the selenium tests. Now if i restart the linux, i want selenium to start automatically. That is, there is should not be a need to start the selenium manually.

So on linux bootup, "I need to open a terminal, and run the command, java -jar selenium-standaloe-xxx.jar"

How can i do so?
My browser will open in the same box. and i am calling my script remotely from putty terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Put your command into

```
/etc/rc.local
```

and reboot, it could be done.